# 0 XMR after mining for 30 hours

Tags: mining

I have been mining monero on my computer with 3 cpu cores and my NVidia 1060 gpu for around 30 hours, but when I check my wallet, it still says, that I have XMR 0.000000000000.
I am on arch linux, if that maes a difference.
Am I missing something really obvious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Am I missing something really obvious?

Yes.

Now, you don't state whether you are solo mining or pool mining so I'll cover both. You also don't state your hashrate, but given your stated hardware of only 3 CPU cores and a mid-range GPU we can use 1.5 KH/s as a modest example - i.e. *very low hashrate*.

Solo mining: you don't earn any XMR till you mine a block. Given your low hashrate, you're looking at *years* before you mine a block, not hours or days.

Pool mining: you don't get paid anything until 1) the pool mines a block in a period you were mining and 2) you have reached the pool's minimum payout threshold. So even assuming #1 (the pool has mined in a block in the last 30 hours), again given your low hashrate, you undoubtedly haven't reached any payout minimum.

Comment: Thanks! I'm really new to crypto mining so I didn't know that.